# what polarisation is assumed when we talk about anti-reflection coating?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, geometric-optics, polarization

When we talk about anti-reflection coating, usually what polarisation ('s' or 'p') are we referring to? Is there a big difference considering that the Fresnal coefficient is different for the two cases?

And if I have no prior knowledge of the property of the light source, and I just assume it is unpolarized, then how do I know which polarisation I should use, or what relative proportion of the two?

Thanks

Comment: 'Unpolarized' will be a 50-50 mix of s and p polarizations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is for normal incidence, in which case polarization does not matter.  If you need oblique incidence you can't get perfect match unless you have and you know the polarization.